# Easiest possible way to retrieve MYSQL data in a table field with decreasing order of occurrence along with the occurrence count?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with the following data:

```
id     product_id

1      31
2      12
3      25
4      31
5      16
6      25
7      31
8      16
```

I want to retrieve the data with decreasing order of occurrence along with the occurrence count as follows:

```
31 - 3 times
25 - 2 times
16 - 2 times
12 - 1 time
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
SELECT
     product_id,
     count(product_id) as times
FROM table_name
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY times desc;
```

Make sure to replace table_name with your actual table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP BY` method.

```
SELECT product_id, count(product_id) as count FROM your_table_name GROUP BY product_id ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Result:

```
product_id - count
    31     - 3 
    25     - 2 
    16     - 2 
    12     - 1
```